# Unhandled Runtime Error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input from SignIn or SignOut next-auth

Tags: javascript, json, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I have next an Unhandled Runtime Error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input when I use SignIn or SignOut with auth credentials.

The error is something weird because show the pop up next error, but register the token and session

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A44E.png)

This is my authorization code with credentials:

```
CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'credentials',
      name: 'Credenciales',

      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (!(credentials.email.length > 0) || !(credentials.password.length > 0)) {
          throw new Error('Email or password was not provided');
        }
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('username', credentials.email);
        formData.append('password', credentials.password);
        formData.append('client_id', credentials.rif);
        
        const url = `${process.env.BACK_ENDPOINT}/login/`
        
        const response = await fetch(url,{
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
        });
        if (response.status === 401) {
          return {
            'details': 'error',
            'message': 'The username or password is not valid'
          }
        }
      
        if (response.status === 500) {
          throw new Error('Have been an error');
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        if (response.status > 400 && response.status < 500) {
          console.error(data)
          if (data.detail) {
            throw data.message;
          }
          throw data;
        }
        if(data.details === 'success'){
          return data
        }
        return null
      }
    }),
```

This is my signIn Callback:

```
signIn: async({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) => {  
      // console.log('signIn', {user, account, profile, email, credentials})
      if (account.type === 'credentials'){
        if(user.details === 'success') return true
        if(user.details === 'error') return false
      }
},
```

And this is my onsubmit handle in frontend:

```
      const objectValues= {
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
        rif: values.rif,
        callbackUrl: '/',
      }
      signIn('credentials', objectValues)
```

Comment: the problem is with what the server responds with ... i.e. it's sending you invalid JSON ... so, all the browser code in the world won't help you fix bad JSON from the server

Comment: I imagined something like this. But looking the network request everything is ok, the response is a json valid

Comment: clearly it isn't, since you get the error - since only you can see the response, I guess we have to rely on your interpretation that the response is indeed "valid JSON" - it must be the browser that is getting it wrong - try a different browser

Comment: I tried with edge, and chrome, I got same error. I always have same response from back_endpoint: {'details': 'error', 'message': 'Error trying to get data'}. I do this for testing. I suppose it is from the next-auth library

Comment: `{'details': 'error', 'message': 'Error trying to get data'}` is not valid JSON

Comment: You are rigth, I wrote without look. Just change the single quotes to doble quotes, and it is ok, isn't?

Answer (score 5):

I find the 'error': in callbacks from [...nextauth].js I had the **redirect** calback without anything there, it always executes with no return:

```
Callbacks:{
    jwt: ({token, user, account, isNewUser}) =>{
        some code...
    },

    redirect: async ({url, baseUrl}) => { 
        // NOTHING OF CODE
    },

    session: ({session, token}) => {
        some code...
    },

    signIn: async({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) => {
        some code...
    }  
}
```

Next time I'm going to give more details about my code and the problem, sorry.
Thanks [@Bravo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10549313/bravo) for your time.